# Finding minimum array of matrix with condition

Tags: matlab

I want to find the minimum of a matrix say `A`. I could do it in this way:

```
NM = find(A==min(A));
```

but I need the minimum array of `A` which for it, `c(NM)` is not zero. How can I put this condition on finding minimum value?

**Example:**

```
c=[0,18,9,0,100,0]; 
A=[1,189,125,25,7,1];
```

I expext it returns 5.

Comment: Don't abuse the `matlab-guide` tag in your  questions.  It is related to  *Graphical User Interfaces Design Environment* in *MATLAB*

Comment: Ok. thanx for informing me @Sardar_Usama

Comment: I would suggest editing the question to add the sample input and output that you provide in the comments to the answers.

Comment: I did ur suggeston. @Cecilia

Comment: Great. That makes it much more clear what you are looking for. rahnema1's answer works for your example.

Comment: Yes and I've chosen it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html) the desired elements.

```
find(A==min(A(c~=0)))
```

Explanation:

Using logical indexing you first find indices of elements of c that are nonzero.

```
idx1 = c~=0;
```

then elements of `A` that correspond to indices of nonzeros elemets of `c` are extracted.

```
A1 = A(idx1);
```

then we find minimum of the extracted elements:

```
mn = min(A1);
```

again we use logical indexing to find elements of A that are equal to its minimum.

```
idx2 = A == mn;
```

finally using `find` the logical index `idx2` converted to linear index.

```
result = find (idx2);
```

Comment: c=[0;0;0;0;0;2;2;2;2;2]; A=[3;3;3;3;3;1;1;1;1;1];  find(c(A==min(A))~=0)

Comment: My Expectation is the code give me number 5:10 but the output is 1:5

Comment: I want elements which A is minimum and c is not zero which is elements 5:10

Comment: If you need elements and not indexes, you can do: `A(A==min(A) & c~=0)`

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. examine c=[0,18,9,0,100,0]; A=[1,189,125,25,7,1]; I expext it returns 5. But it doesn't

Comment: @saranj sorry for late reply. I was not online. Answer updated based on  your last example.

Comment: It's exactly the case. Thank you for your big help :)

Comment: Glad if it can help

Answer (score 0):

First convert your Matrix to a vector (otherwise the minimum of a Matrix is confusing, it might mean the minimum of each column).

Then you can sort the Vector and get the indexes

```
[val idx] = sort(A(:));
```

You can then use the indexes to sort your vector c

```
c = c(idx);
```

And finally get the first non-zero element of c:

```
c = c(c~=0);    
result = c(1);
```

Comment: c=[0,18,9,0,100,0];
A=[1,189,125,25,7,1];
[val idx] = sort(A(:));
c = c(idx);                                                                                                                    c = c(c~=0);    
result = c(1)

Comment: Please run above code. I expect it returns 5, because the element in A which is the minimum element for which c is not equal to zero, is the 5th element.